# remove zero lines 2-D numpy array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

I run a `qr factorization` in `numpy` which returns a list of `ndarrays`, namely `Q`and `R`:

```
>>> [q,r] = np.linalg.qr(np.array([1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]).reshape(3,3))
```

`R` is a two-dimensional array, having pivoted zero-lines at the bottom (even proved for all examples in my test set):

```
>>> print r
[[ 1.41421356  0.70710678  0.70710678]
 [ 0.          1.22474487  1.22474487]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]]
```

. Now, I want to divide `R` in two matrices `R_~`:

```
[[ 1.41421356  0.70710678  0.70710678]
 [ 0.          1.22474487  1.22474487]]
```

and `R_0`:

```
[[ 0.          0.          0.        ]]
```

(extracting all zero-lines). It seems to be close to this solution: [deleting rows in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877491/deleting-rows-in-numpy-array).

EDIT:
Even more interesting: `np.linalg.qr()` returns a `n x n`-matrix. Not, what I would have expected:

```
A := n x m
Q := n x m
R := n x m
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Use `np.all` with an `axis` argument:

```
>>> r[np.all(r == 0, axis=1)]
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> r[~np.all(r == 0, axis=1)]
array([[-1.41421356, -0.70710678, -0.70710678],
       [ 0.        , -1.22474487, -1.22474487]])
```

Comment: @denfromufa `axis=0` would remove all-zero *columns*.

Comment: that is obvious, what is problematic is that this filtering cannot be applied as is for `axis=0`, instead transpose is necessary

Comment: @denfromufa oh yeah, you need to do the subscript on the 1 axis: `r[:, np.all(r == 0, axis=0)]`

Comment: @denfromufa or   `s.compress(np.all(s == 0, axis=0), axis=1)`

Answer (score 5):

Because the data are not equal zero exactly, we need set a threshold value for zero such as 1e-6, use numpy.all with axis=1 to check the rows are zeros or not. Use numpy.where and numpy.diff to get the split positions, and call numpy.split to split the array into a list of arrays.

```
import numpy as np
[q,r] = np.linalg.qr(np.array([1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]).reshape(3,3))
mask = np.all(np.abs(r) < 1e-6, axis=1)
pos = np.where(np.diff(mask))[0] + 1
result = np.split(r, pos)
```

Comment: You think, 1e-6 should be precise enough for most purposes? Should I learn this paramater?

Comment: @MillaWell the precision always depend on application. For example, a precision of one milimeter is very good for civil engineering, but very poor for mechanical engineering, and somewhat absurd for astronomy, for example.

Comment: numpy now has `np.allclose` function which can make the code more readable https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html

Answer (score 5):

Since this is among the first google results to **trim** a 2D array of zero lines, I want to add my implementation to only remove leading and trailing zeros, in two dimensions:

```
p = np.where(t != 0)
t = t[min(p[0]) : max(p[0]) + 1, min(p[1]) : max(p[1]) + 1]
```

This assumes your array is called `t` and numpy is imported as `np`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to eliminate rows that have negligible entries, i'd use `np.allclose`.

```
zero_row_indices = [i for i in r.shape[0] if np.allclose(r[i,:],0)]
nonzero_row_indices =[i for i in r.shape[0] if not np.allclose(r[i,:],0)]
r_new = r[nonzero_row_indices,:]
```