# Numpy remove columns and rows that only have False or 0 in one line

Tags: python, numpy

**Similar question which shows how to do column *or* row**: [remove zero lines 2-D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188364/remove-zero-lines-2-d-numpy-array)

I'm looking for a ***one liner*** that can remove rows and columns from an array that only have `False` or `0`. I can currently do this in two lines as follows and my attempt at doing it in one line will be shown.

> Consider array:

```
arr = array([[[False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
              [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
              [False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
              [False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
              [False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
              [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
              [False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]])
```

> Remove rows

```
arr_2 = arr[~np.all(arr == False, axis=1), :]
arr_2
array([[False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False]])
```

> Remove columns

```
arr_3 = arr_2[:, ~np.all(arr_2 == False, axis=0)]
arr_3
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

This achieves the desired outcome. I think this should be doable in one line.

**My attempt at one line**

```
arr_4 = arr[~np.all(arr == False, axis=1), ~np.all(arr == False, axis=0)]
arr_4 = array([ True,  True,  True])
```

Obviously this is not the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create open indexing arrays with [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) and then index into input array -

```
arr[np.ix_(np.any(arr, axis=1),np.any(arr, axis=0))]
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly using `arr[np.ix_(~np.all(arr==False,axis=1),~np.all(arr==False,axis=0))]`

Comment: I've not used `np.ix_` before. Reading the document it looks quite useful.