# Delete zero rows from np.array

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I need to load an image, convert it into a np.array and then delete all rows that contains all zeros.
For load the image I use:

```
image = Image.open(path).convert(mode='L')  
image = (np.array(image,dtype=int))
```

The image is a B/W image where the black is 0 and the white is 1. The image is like:

```
0000000000100000000001000000
0000000000000000010000000000
0000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000
0000010011000000001110000000
```

And I need to delete all zeros row to get something like:

```
0000000000100000000001000000
0000000000000000010000000000
0000010011000000001110000000
```

Is there a numpy function to do this? Am I doing it in the right way?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove zero lines 2-D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188364/remove-zero-lines-2-d-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
new_image = []

for i in range(image.shape[1]):
    if 1 in image[i,:]:
        new_image.append(image[i,:])
    else:
        continue
```

You can then convert back to a numpy array just using

```
new_image = np.array(new_image)
```