# delete every nth row or column in a matrix using Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am trying to delete every 8th column in a 1024x1024 matrix using this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877491/deleting-rows-in-numpy-array) but it takes a lot of time and it will be more difficult when I have to process millions of matrices. Could you please show me how can I delete every nth row or column starting from a certain row or column and using numpy, scipy or any other Python package?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `np.delete` giving the indices corresponding to every 8th row index. Let `a` be a 2D array or a matrix:

```
np.delete(a, list(range(0, a.shape[0], 8)), axis=0)
```

note the use of `axis=0` indicating to operate along the rows. To operate along the columns:

```
np.delete(a, list(range(0, a.shape[1], 8)), axis=1)
```