# Delete all numbers from an array which are in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array "removable" containing a few numbers from another array "All" containing all numbers from 0 to k.

I want to remove all numbers in A which are listed in removable.

```
All = np.arange(k)
removable = np.ndarray([1, 3, 4 , 7, 9, ..., 200])

for i in removable:
    if i in All:
        All.remove(i)
```

ndarray has no remove attribute, but I'm sure there is an easy method in numpy to solve this problem, but I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Why not use lists?

Comment: I get the removable from another method, sadly im not able to change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the function [setdiff1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) from NumPy:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1])
>>> b = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> np.setdiff1d(a, b)
array([1, 2])
```

Comment: Note that this will de-duplicate the original entries in `a` (not done by the pseudocode in the question), and the result will be sorted

Comment: Thats true, however the np.arange(k) provides a list without duplicates.
My answer will not work with duplicates.

Comment: Oh snap, `setdiff1d` is even faster than explicit set conversion and differencing. I guess that makes sense, probably more optimized. I didn't know numpy had this!

Comment: Now the question is if OP wants duplicates or deduplicates

Answer (score 2):

`np.setdiff1d()` will de-duplicate the original entries, and will also return the result sorted.

That's fine in some cases, but if you want to avoid one or both of these aspects, have a look at `np.in1d()` with an (inverted) boolean mask:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1])                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
>>> b = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6])                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>>> a[~np.in1d(a, b)]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
array([1, 2, 2, 1])
```

The `~` operator does inversion on the boolean mask:

```
>>> np.in1d(a, b)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
array([False, False,  True, False,  True, False])

>>> ~np.in1d(a, b)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
array([ True,  True, False,  True, False,  True])
```

Disclaimer:

Note that this is not truly *removal*, as you indicated in your question; the result is a [view](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) into filtered elements of the original array `a`.  Same goes for [`np.delete()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426697/is-there-any-way-to-delete-the-specific-elements-of-an-numpy-array-in-place-in); there's no concept of in-place element deletion for NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** - fast for big arrays, no need to transform into list (slowing down computation)

```
orig=np.arange(15)
to_remove=np.array([1,2,3,4])
mask = np.isin(orig, to_remove)
orig=orig[np.invert(mask)]

>>> orig
array([ 0,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

Comment: `np.isin()` calls `np.asarray()` + `np.in1d()` and does reshaping.  If both of the inputs are 1d, those checks are probably not needed

Comment: no need to say its impossible or to give different solution than what is being asked from OP

Comment: constructive criticism always welcome. We are all fellow programmers here, some having learnt a lot already, others just starting. Help correct mistakes or dont, but there is absolutely no need to mock them.

Answer (score -1):

numpy arrays have a fixed shape, you cannot remove elements from them.

You cannot do this with ndarrays.

Comment: Upvote to counter the downvotes. Perhaps pedantic, but not incorrect. And not an unimportant aspect about ndarrays to appreciate, on the path to a good solution to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should do this with sets instead of lists/arrays, which is easy enough:

```
remaining = np.array(set(arr).difference(removable))
```

where `arr` is your `All` array above ("all" is a keyword and should not be overwritten).

Granted, using sets will get rid of repeated elements if you have those in your `arr`, but it sounds like `arr` is just a sequence of unique values. Sets have much more efficient membership checking (constant-time vs. order N), so you get to go a lot faster. By comparison, I made a list version that builds a list if a value is *not* in `removable`:

```
def remove_list(arr, rem):
    result = []
    for i in arr:
        if i not in rem:
            result.append(i)
    return result
```

and made my set version a function as well:

```
def remove_set(arr, rem):
    return np.array(set(arr).difference(rem))
```

Timing comparison with `arr = np.arange(10000)` and `removable = np.random.randint(0, 10000, 1000)`:

```
remove_list(arr, removable)
# 55.5 ms ± 664 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

remove_set(arr, removable)
# 947 µs ± 3.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Set is 50 times faster.