# MemoryError in numpy.delete

Tags: numpy, memory, python-3.6

I am downloading some data from the db, storing in a numpy array, and performing some clean up on the array based 
on the contents of a particular column. This is my code that I am using to delete some rows :

```
def clean_data(data,column):
    target_data = data[:,column].astype(int)
    pos_to_delete = np.where(target_data==1)[0]
    data = np.delete(data,pos_to_delete,axis=0)
    return data
```

I get the following error in numpy.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "data_download.py", line 111, in download_data
data = clean_data(data)
File "/home/work/data_clean.py", line 13, in data_clean.py
data = np.delete(data,pos_to_delete,axis=0)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4262, in delete
new = arr[tuple(slobj)]
MemoryError
```

PS - If I get data from the db and dunp to a file, then read this file and perform clean up, this error does'nt show anymore.
Solutions to this question [Is there any way to delete the specific elements of an numpy array "In-place" in python:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426697/is-there-any-way-to-delete-the-specific-elements-of-an-numpy-array-in-place-in) 
are'nt helping. How do I delete with inplace=True and also take care of the Memory issue?
Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is produced when `delete` creates the array that will return the result.  It then intends to fill it with the 'keeper' values from the source.  `delete` always returns a new array.  Looks like other objects such as the source DataFrame are taking up a lot of memory, leaving little memory for further manipulation.

Comment: What's the size (shape) of `target_data` and `pos_to_delete`?

Comment: Data shape is (5L,40), so target data is (5L,1)

Comment: Doesn't seem large enough to cause memory errors.

Answer (score 0):

`np.delete` takes several routes depending on nature of the `obj` array.  In this, case where it is generated by `where`, and thus is an array of indices to remove, it takes the following route:

```
def foo1(data, idx):
    msk = np.ones(data.shape[0],bool)
    msk[idx] = False
    return data[msk, :]
```

That is it constructs a boolean mask True, and sets the selected items to False.  `arr[tuple(slobj)]` is a slightly more general version to handle the axis parameter.  But in your case axis is 0, so I can simplify it to `[msk,:]`.

So the `msk` is just a 1d boolean the size of the number of rows of your `data`.

`np.delete(target_data,pos_to_delete,axis=0)` would return the `target_data` column minus the deletes, a fairly small 1d array.

`np.delete(data, ...)` will return an array of comparable size to `data`, minus however many you delete.

This makes me think that your `data` is so large that there's barely any room to do any calculations with it, even something so simple as making a copy.

Comment: So what is the solution then?