# Slicing from one dimension of 3D Numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing

I have 3D array with (1000, 256, 256) shape. I want to take away the 100-200th entry from the x dimension (with 1000 items). Writing [0:100, 101:1001] makes the cut from the second dimension (with 256 items).

How do I index it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to crop an image in OpenCV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877491/deleting-rows-in-numpy-array)

Comment: I accidentally clicked the wrong link for the duplicate. The correct link and description should be: [deleting rows in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877491/deleting-rows-in-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. Either slice two times and concatenate manually:

```
arr = np.random.rand(1000, 256, 256)

arr2 = np.vstack((arr[:100], arr[200:]))
```

Or use `np.delete`:

```
arr3 = np.delete(arr, slice(100, 200), axis=0)
```

Both results are equal:

```
np.all(arr2 == arr3)
# Out: True
```